# how to check type of object in C++

Tags: c++

In java, there is a keyword "instanceof", which can be used to determine the type of object. In C++, the only solution i found so far was to use dynamic_cast. This approach  is not only bad, but it is also very expensive. The reason it is bad is because the flow of control is driven by catching exceptions. Exception in my mind should only be used for "Exceptional" situations and not to control the main flow of code.

Imagine a use case, where a network handler can receive different types of messages. This handler can have a long list of try catch blocks with each block trying a dynamic_cast. It could be possible that for every single message, there would be many exceptions raised, till the flow finally finds the correct type. This also kills the performance in the application as catching exception is not cheap.

Can you please suggest alternatives to dynamic_cast, similar to java's instanceof operator, so that i can avoid exception catching overhead?

UPDATE: Any solution other than RTTI would be great as RTTI is also expensive. Perhaps , i can just put string names in the messages and map strings to objects?

Comment: Google RTTI, but it ain't as flexible nor as reflexive as Java's or that of Objective-C.

Comment: when you cast the pointer to the object, it does not throw an exception, but returns 0 instead, right? http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: It doesn't need exceptions. `dynamic_cast<Type*>(this)` will return a NULL pointer if the conversion doesn't apply.

Comment: @Corijn a bad cast would throw std::bad_cast

Comment: @PeteBecker that is true in case of pointers, but in case of references , you will get a std::bad_cast

Comment: Have **you** measured RTTI and determined that it's too expensive? Granted, lots of people **say** it is, but they're mostly wrong.

Comment: @Jimm "When dynamic_cast cannot cast a pointer because it is not a complete object of the required class -as in the second conversion in the previous example- it returns a null pointer to indicate the failure. If dynamic_cast is used to convert to a reference type and the conversion is not possible, an exception of type bad_cast is thrown instead." http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: "RTTI is expensive" is as ridiculous as measuring clock cycles in every line of code.

Comment: @Jimm - so don't use `dynamic_cast` on a reference. Take the address and use the pointer. No exceptions involved.

Comment: @PeteBecker Expensive is relative. But imagine a usecase, where you are processing 100k messages per second. At this rate, RTTI's cost becomes significant if it is incurred on per message basis.

Comment: @Jimm expensive compared to what?

Comment: @Jimm - sorry, I don't do imaginary designs. **Measure it**. And **measure** the alternatives that you're thinking of. And then, based on **real information**, determine what the best approach is. "RTTI's cost becomes significant" is just handwaving if you haven't measured it.

Comment: If you design your program in a way that makes RTTI unnecessary, the problem goes away. Your specific example wouldn't use it anyway, so this sounds like a purely hypothetical question.

Comment: @PeteBecker i profiled my entire app and it is 16.60% in my use case.

Comment: @Jimm what platform is this on? sometimes `dynamic_cast` uses string comparisons on mangled names underneath, sometimes it just compares addresses, it depends on the ABI; the latter is much faster.

Comment: @Jimm you can also hand-roll your own RTTI if you control the message classes and make it much faster, see LLVM's internal RTTI mechanism as an example: http://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html; basically you just set up an enumeration that identifies each type and make sure to set it properly in the constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator. That returns [`type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) objects, which can be compared for equality. Alternatively, `dynamic_cast` pointers, that returns null instead of throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serialising objects over a network, I assume you have some kind of factory which can recreate them from the wire.

The factory has a switch statement, or a map or something which allows you to create the correct object. It doesn't use runtime-type information.

The objects you create will have some common base. Create your hierarchy from there. If there isn't some common behaviour expected of all objects in the hierarchy, use the `Visitor` pattern to add behaviour dynamically:

```
struct Derived;

struct Visitor {
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) = 0;
};

struct Base {
    virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor) = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(*this);
    }
};
```

The `Visitor` pattern is most appropriate when you have a relatively stable hierarchy, and want a changeable set of behaviours. If you have an unstable hierarchy but a stable set of behaviours you can just do what's normal and have the `Base` class interface define the behaviours to be implemented by derived classes.